# Getting PATH variable in NSIS script

Tags: environment-variables, nsis

I can't figure out how to get to the PATH variable in an NSIS script. Here's what I tried, but it returns 'error' in $0:

```
nsExec::ExecToStack 'echo %PATH%'
Pop $0
MessageBox MB_OK "$0"
```

Also tried escaping the % signs with $s, to no avail. Putting just some string instead of %PATH% also does not work. I saw a suggested example just like this one using Exec instead of ExecToStack, but that did not work either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSIS already has a built-in instruction for this: `ReadEnvStr $0 PATH`.

`ExecToStack` did not work because `echo` is a internal command in cmd.exe, not a .exe. You would have to execute it as `cmd.exe /c echo %path%`.

Remember that %path% can be longer than the NSIS string limit so you should not write it back to the registry after storing it in a NSIS variable. Use the [EnVar plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/EnVar_plug-in) to safely modify %path%.

Comment: I'm getting null when using the "ReadEnvStr $0 PATH", I ran both the the PowerShell to create the .exe and product. This is the short version of my code
Section
  ReadEnvStr $0 PATH
  DetailPrint "EnVar::Check returned=|$0|"
  MessageBox MB_OK "PATH Environment Variable: $checkResult"
SectionEnd

Comment: @PromodKumar You should not read %path% into a register if you can avoid it. You can read other variables with ReadEnvStr though...